# FlatFileFooterCallback Exception not coming in Skip Listener

Tags: spring-batch

Issue :- Error throwing from FlatFileFooterCallback is not skippable and Job is getting stopped
What we tried

Job Configuration below

```
    @Bean
public Step mmsSlaveStep() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("mmsSlaveStep").<BaseDTO, BaseDTO>chunk(chunkSize).reader(mmsReader(null))
            .processor(mmsProcessor()).writer(mmsItemWriter(null)).faultTolerant().skipLimit(skipErrorCount)
            .skip(Exception.class).listener(itemSkipListener()).build();
}
```

ItemWriter that have Footer Call Back

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<BaseDTO> mmsItemWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filePath)
        throws Exception {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<BaseDTO> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    fieldExtractor.setNames(mmsWriterFields);
    fieldExtractor.afterPropertiesSet();
    FormatterLineAggregator<BaseDTO> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setFormat(mmsWriterFieldsFormat);
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(filePath);
    Resource outputResource = new FileSystemResource(new File(sucessPath + fileName + inputDataSource));
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<BaseDTO>().name("mmsWriter").resource(outputResource)
            .lineAggregator(lineAggregator).shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true).footerCallback(mmsSummaryItemWriter()).build();
}
```

FooterCall Back Writer that have writeFooter that aggregates data to a DB table. This exception is not coming to SkipListener

public class MMSSummaryWriter implements FlatFileFooterCallback {

```
@Autowired
private MMSMasterService mmsMasterService;
@Value("#{stepExecution}")
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



@Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException{
        ExecutionContext  executionContext =stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    HashMap<String,MMSDto> summaryMap = (HashMap<String, MMSDto>) executionContext.get("Summary"); 
    
    List<MMSDto> summaryValues = new ArrayList<>(summaryMap.values());
    
        
    int[] updateCounts =  jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(InterConnectUtils.SUMMARY_EVENT_INSERT, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
              @Override
              public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException   {
                  int counter =0;
                  MMSDto mmsDto = summaryValues.get(i);
                  ps.setString(1,mmsDto.getBatchNumber());
                  ps.setString(2,mmsDto.getEntityCode());
                  ps.setString(3,mmsDto.getInputFileType());
                  ps.setInt(4, mmsDto.getTotalType());
                  ps.setString(5,mmsDto.getServiceType());
                  ps.setString(6, mmsDto.getCallInd());
                  ps.setString(7,mmsDto.getCallDateTime());
                  ps.setString(8,mmsDto.getEventDirection());
                  ps.setString(9,mmsDto.getProductID());
                  ps.setInt(10,mmsDto.getTargetInd());
                  ps.setInt(11,mmsDto.getNoRecords());
                  ps.setLong(26,mmsDto.getTotalDuration());
                System.out.println("InsertValues : "+mmsDto.getBatchNumber()+"#"+mmsDto.getTotalType()+"#"+mmsDto.getCallInd()+"#"+mmsDto.getServiceType()+"#"+
                        mmsDto.getProductID()+"#"+mmsDto.getCallDateTime()+"#"+mmsDto.getTotalType());
              }
              @Override
              public int getBatchSize() {
                  System.out.println("summaryMap.size()"+summaryMap.size());
                return summaryMap.size();
              }
              
            });
    
}
```

}

SkipListner Class that handles errors and log to table and allow the job to continue

```
public class PreProcSkipListener implements SkipListener<BaseDTO, BaseDTO> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreProcSkipListener.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void onSkipInWrite(BaseDTO item, Throwable t) {
    Exception ex = new Exception(t);
    jdbcTemplate.update(InterConnectUtils.BATCH_ERROR_INSERT, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            MMSDto mmsDto = (MMSDto) item;
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new Date().getTime()));
            ps.setString(2, mmsDto.getBatchNumber());
            ps.setString(3, "WRITER");
            Reader reader = new StringReader(exceptionAsString + "--" + ex.getMessage());
            ps.setClob(4, reader);
        }

    });

    }
   }}
```

There is an open issue mentioned in github to consider. Let us know any workaround
[github defect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1209)